# How to update google-chrome on centos with yum-cron?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, yum, chrome

I'm managing a medium size Selenium grid based on Linux CentOS 7 - a total of a couple dozens linux VMs. I'm using yum-cron to install updates.  Starting recently, google-chrome does not update automatically any more, as the signature on the RPM does not match the specified repo gpg signature.

There are plenty of posts on the internet about this issue - and plenty of people saying that Google wouldn't be fixing the issue.

There is a workaround published - to use rpm with --nogpg switch to update google-chrome, then update the rest of the system as normal.  I have two issues with this workaround:

1. I don't feel comfortable to just disable signature check when installing software from a remote repo
2. I can't manually specify any switches anyway, as all the updates are automated and run overnight

My question is: how can I continue updating the system automatically with yum-cron or some in other manner *and* get the google-chrome package updated along with the rest of the system?